# For a singly linked list, does a new node always have to be added as the first element?

Tags: singly-linked-list

Usually in a singly linked list, do you always add a new element as a head.next, in other words as the first element? Or do you walk to the end of the list and add it there?

Comment: You can add it at the beginning, the end, or even in the middle, depending on what is needed.

Comment: If you provide an add(Entry e) functionality. Where would you typically add it?

Comment: You can add it wherever you want. If you only have a pointer to the first element of the list (called *head*), then adding a new element at the beginning takes `O(1)`, while inserting it at the end takes `O(n)` where `n` is the size of the linked list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oncv0UlcUR0) from Stanford university (after 13:00 min), add walks to the end of the list and adds the new node there. Here is a screen shot of the code (C++)
[image]

In the [lecture notes from UC Berkley (Java)](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61b/lec/07), they add it as the first item, but then they explicitly call it out as insertFront()

```
public class SList {
  private SListNode head;             // First node in list.
  private int size;                   // Number of items in list.

  public SList() {                    // Here's how to represent an empty list.
    head = null;
    size = 0;
  }

  public void insertFront(Object item) {
    head = new SListNode(item, head);
    size++;
  }
}
```

In the [LinkedList class in java framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add-E-) (this is doubly linked list), just add means add to the end of the list. So if you add 1, then 2 and then 3, 3 will be the last item in the list.

**In short:** Unless explicitly called out as addFront (or something like that), add on a LinkedList, means add as the last item.

Answer (score 0):

Either way is possible, but inserting at the front is usually preferred for performance reasons.

Inserting a new element as the head is very fast, O(1), because you only need to create an element and a pointer to the old head.

Inserting at the end means walking the list to find the last element and updating it's pointer to the new element. This is O(n).

You can trade time for storage by keeping track of the tail of your list as well and make O(1) insertions to the end. But then you've got something a little more complicated than a singly linked list.

**Qualifying Usually**

When I say *usually*, I'm referring to hand crafted singly linked lists, especially written in C, perhaps for some embedded device where space is at a premium and the extra space to store the tail is just too much.

For a general purpose language like, say, Java, the LinkedList implementation stores the tail so both operations are O(1). Interestingly, in the Java case, the abstract interface for List only defines an operation that appends to the list.

**An implementation (in pseudo C)**

Let's say I have some list such as

```
struct List {
    int data;
    List *next;
};
```

If I want to insert in the beginning, I'll write

```
List* insert(List *original_list, int data) {
    List* head = allocate new List(data, original_list);
    return head;
}
```

If I want to append, I'll write

```
void append(List *original_list, int data) {
    List* new_tail = allocate new List(data, null);
    ptr = original_list
    while(ptr->next != null)
        ptr++
    ptr->next = new_tail;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @munk stated, either way is possible. However, the time complexity of insertion can vary depending on the structure you're using. Let me be more clear.
Let's use C lang just to make it straightforward. A possible way to implement a single linked list is this:

```
typedef struct node {
    int foo;
    node_t* next;
} node_t;

typedef struct list {
    node_t* head;
} list_t;
```

In this way, you first create a structure `node` to store the info you want to store, and then declare a second structure `list` which simply contains a pointer to the first node of the list, i.e. the `head`. With this implementation:

- Inserting at the beginning takes `O(1)` time (you have only to change the `head` field and made some adjustments with `next`.
- Inserting at the end takes `O(n)` time cause you have to walk the entire list.

A second way to implement a single linked list is this:

```
typedef struct node {
    int foo;
    node_t* next;
} node_t;

typedef struct list {
    node_t* head;
    node_t* tail;
} list_t;
```

You maintain a pointer to the **last** element of the list, which makes the insertion at the end take `O(1)` time, too. However, this kind of implementation takes up more space than the other one.